# "Have been the US" vs "Have been to the US"

Tags: phrase-usage

I am wondering which the sentence is correct:

> 1. I have been **to** the US.
> 2. I have been the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 is correct. You *must* use the preposition "to." Sentence 2, without the preposition, means you have literally been the United States -- that somehow you literally are the country. It doesn't make sense, even in informal usage or slang.

Comment: One follow-up question, is "I have been in the US" correct? If yes, what would be the difference from "I have been to the US"?

Comment: *I have been to the US* and *I have been in the US* mean basically the same thing. There may be a slight difference in connotation. *To the US* might suggest that you were visiting on vacation from another country, whereas *in the US* suggests that maybe you spent a longer period of time, perhaps residing in the US rather than just visiting. But like I said, the difference, if any, is minimal.

Comment: For example, you could say ***I have been in the US for five years***, meaning you have lived in the US for that long. But you can't say ***I have been to the US for five years***. That doesn't make sense.